# Triple homebrew git available

Tags: git, homebrew, apple-m1

I did a fresh install of homebrew as I am on an Apple Silicon Macbook Pro and got a bit sceptical if I did things wrong. Now its fine but I ran into this problem earlier where after doing `brew install git` my Git version was still the Apple one when doing `which git`. After doing some searching I used `brew doctor` which outputted me to use `echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`. This command solved all of my problems now but the thing I have an issue with is that I did it 3 times. So what happened was I did it once, typed `which git` and it was still Apple. Not knowing I had to open a new terminal window I did it two more times. I thought why not close terminal and then boom it worked.

My Git works fine and I have set everything up, just a bit annoying knowing theres another 2 duplicates. Hopefully it isnt a big deal.

Keep in mind I am a complete beginner so try to word things in a way I could understand. I have not mastered the terminal yet. Thanks.

My question is how do I remove these 3 extra places when typing `which -a git`? I get this when doing so:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/git
/opt/homebrew/bin/git
/opt/homebrew/bin/git
/usr/bin/git
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check and edit your `~/.zshrc`: if you see `export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"` repeated three times, that would explain your `which` output.

Make sure there is only one `export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"` in  `~/.zshrc`, in order for the `$PATH` to not include three identical paths.