# Git version in the terminal is not the same as in Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, macos, visual-studio-code, terminal, git-update-ref

I tried to update Git on Mac terminal by using [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) (`brew`) and everything looked good except the directory was different in the terminal. Command "which git" gives me */opt/homebrew/bin/git*, and the version is 2.34.

But in Visual Studio Code it says */usr/bin/git*. Here the version is 2.30.

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio Code? Please respond by [editing (changing) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70046054/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the setting "`Git Path`" was set directly to `/usr/bin/git`.

[image: VSCode settings]

If so, you can delete that setting: VSCode will pick up `git` from the `$PATH`.

As long as which git displays `/opt/homebrew/bin/git` *before* `/usr/bin/git`, you will be OK.

The [OP MadCodex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17434309/madcodex) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70046054/git-version-in-terminal-not-the-same-as-vscode/70046165#comment123822841_70046165):

> I just deleted the brew git and everything come to normal again

I would not recommend that "solution", as the [brew git is the one which is supposed to be here](http://I%20just%20deleted%20the%20brew%20git%20and%20everything%20come%20to%20normal%20again%20%E2%80%93).

From [the discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239417/discussion-between-vonc-and-madcodex), adding  `export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"` in `~/.zshr` and relaunching VSCode was enough.

Comment: git: '/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin' is not a git command. See 'git --help'. <-- this from the terminal

Comment: git: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin' is not a git command. See 'git --help'. <--- this from vsCode

Comment: @MadCodex In the terminal, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65605464/6309: make sure your zshrc or bashrc does set the PATH correctly.

Comment: I just deleted the brew git and everything come to normal again

Comment: @MadCodex brew git? That is the one which is supposed to be here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/426290 The latest one 2.34

Comment: because I couldn't uninstall vscode so I said I will delete git from brew first and begin from the beginning

Comment: @MadCodex No need to uninstall anything: just remove the VSCode settings, and reload VSCode.

Comment: I am sorry but how I do that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239417/discussion-between-vonc-and-madcodex).